# gcc: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000010)

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, mingw, console2

I've been searching around for an answer to this for a while but haven't been able to find a solution.  Basically, I'm using MinGW and when trying to compile any piece of C code, I get this message:  "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000010)."  I've been using the compiler for a few weeks now and this error has just suddenly come up. It happens whether I compile through Console2, PyCmd, or cmd.  I've tried reinstalling MinGW and checked dependencies through Dependency Walker, which only shows up with the standard (apparently) GPSVC.DLL and IESHIMS.DLL errors.

Thanks in advance.